# WCF service for consumption by jQuery: works with VS dev server, but not with IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, wcf, web-services

This has been driving me nuts today. Hopefully someone here can help me crack it.

Basically, I have created a test site with a WCF service to be consumed by jQuery. It has three methods, two of which work perfectly.

The service returns JSON. It has three methods, two of which work perfectly. The third does not - and I cannot see why.

This is what I do know.

If I launch the site from Visual Studio, I can browse to the service and view the formatted JSON. If I try to do the same in a browser i.e. the IIS version, I get a 400 error. But only for the one method - the others are fine.

It's that inconsistency that has me stumped.

I have set it up as a website in IIS, rather than a virtual directory. To browse to it, the URL is of the form http://mytestsite.local

Having followed a walk-through (it has been a while since I have done any WCF work!), I took the approach of removing service-related configuration info from web.config. Instead, I have a Factory attribute that references the class WebServiceHostFactory in the .svc file.

Here are the methods:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public UserDTO[] GetUsers()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new GSChallengeContext())
        {
            var results = from u in dbContext.Users
                          select new UserDTO()
                          {
                              UserId = u.UserId,
                              Forename = u.Forename,
                              Surname = u.Surname,
                          };
            return results.ToArray();
        }
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public UserDTO[] GetUserById(int userId)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new GSChallengeContext())
        {
            var results = from u in dbContext.Users
                          where u.UserId == userId
                          select new UserDTO()
                          {
                              UserId = u.UserId,
                              Forename = u.Forename,
                              Surname = u.Surname,
                              DateOfBirth = (DateTime)u.DateOfBirth
                          };
            return results.ToArray();
        }
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public VehicleDTO[] GetVehiclesByUserId(int userId)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new GSChallengeContext())
        {
            var results = from v in dbContext.Vehicles
                          where v.UserId == userId
                          select new VehicleDTO()
                          {
                              VehicleId = v.VehicleId,
                              UserId = v.UserId,
                              Registration = v.Registration,
                              Alias = v.Alias,
                              Disabled = v.Disabled
                          };
            return results.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

This is the code that makes the call:

```
    function ShowUserVehicleInfo()
    {
        var userId = $("#users").val();
        var outStr = "";
        $.getJSON('Services/GSChallenge.svc/GetVehiclesByUserId?userId=' + userId,
            function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, elem) {
                    outStr += "<div class=\"vehicleData\">" +
                            "<p>Registration: " + elem.Registration + "</p>" +
                            "<p>Alias: " + elem.Alias + "</p>" +
                            "<p>Disabled: " + elem.Disabled + "</p>" +
                            "</div>"
                });
            }
        );
    }
```

I have searched before posting, but have not yet found anything that solves the problem - or even helps.

Can anyone help?

Comment: could put the code which make the call? And endpoint Web.config section for de service? 400 error  = Bad Request

Comment: The calling code does not seem to be the problem, though - I can browse to the service and see formatted JSON, using VS development server. It fails if I try it using IIS.

Comment: Ok. then you have not set anything about the service in the web.config? there is any possibility that method returns a large amount of data?

Comment: That's correct - nothing in the web.config. Not much data returned; probably less than 2Kb

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, but it is somewhat strange that happens to you ... you've used Firefox / Firebug to view response/request headers, when running ok and when not working ?

Comment: That's OK. :-) Yes, I have. There are differences between the response headers: content type and content length are different. (text/html for IIS, application/JSON for development server.

Comment: Great!! Have you found the error! The method expects application / JSON. 400 error is a typical error for that. Have you tried using getJSON in both IIS and Dev Server?

Comment: I wish it was that. Yes, I have used getJSON in the jQuery functions to consume the service. But the error is occurring before jQuery becomes involved. Those headers are from when I browse to the service directly, not when I request the aspx page. I cannot understand why the difference is there.

Comment: One last test before making changes ... please check the headers in IIS when you invoke via getJSON GetUserById and Compare with GetVehiclesByUserId.

Comment: It's the same. Very frustrating.

Comment: Yes. text/html when served by IIS, application/JSON when served by development server. I think it's time to call it a night. Maybe when I look again with fresh eyes and brain I'll spot the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I may have stumbled across the cause; I changed one of the fields in my database from nchar(10) to nvarchar(10). Hey presto: no more 400 bad request error!

I'm not entirely sure why this fixed the problem - but I'm glad it did!

Answer (score 1):

This gave me my result to a similar scenario ...

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
         <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

GSChallenge definition

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
 public class GSChallenge
```

Comment: Your help is much appreciated. Unfortunately the suggestions above have not resolved the problem. It's as though the last method in the service is causing the wrong response type headers - despite the fact that its implementation is identical to the other two service methods that work fine. More head scratching to do!